# get the number of records from a year

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write some PHP code so that when a user enters a quote, the application looks at the quote table, counts how many quotes have been raised for that year, then adds 1 to the count, the end result is to provide a unique and sequential quote number for that year.  The format is supposed to be Q/YY/sequential number

```
//Insert New Q Reference
    //set standards
    $time=strtotime($values['QuoteDate']);
    $LongYear=date("Y",$time);
    $ShortYear=date("y",$time);

    //Get current number quotes for the year which quote was issued
    global $dal;
    $dal_table = $dal->Table("quotations"); 
    if ($values["QuoteDate"])
        { 
            $rstmp = CustomQuery("select count(*) as count1 from quotations where '$LongYear' = ".$LongYear); 
            $datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp); 
            $count_value = 0;   
            if ($datatmp["count1"]) $count_value = $datatmp["count1"];

            $values['QuoteReference'] = 'Q/'.$ShortYear.'/'.str_pad(($count_value+1), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        }
```

The problem i am having is that the code is just returning the total sequential number + 1 and it is not taking into account the count of the year!

See the following screenshot, the 2018 is supposed to be Q/18/0001

[image]

Comment: What is the column name for the year on quotations table? I think the issue is on that part

Comment: Hi the column name is QuoteDate

Comment: Your query is wrong then,      $rstmp = CustomQuery("select count(*) as count1 from quotations where '$LongYear' = ".$LongYear); 

Should be:
 $rstmp = CustomQuery("select count(*) as count1 from quotations where QuoteDate = ".$LongYear);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are comparing

```
'$LongYear' = ".$LongYear
```

this will always succeed. You should be comparing the year from the value of the column instead:

```
YEAR(QuoteDate) = ".$LongYear
```